# cmd line to run spyder under specific anaconda environment

Tags: shell, spyder, anaconda3

I have a very nice steelseries apex raw keyboard with programmable keys. I would like to run spyder with a specific conda environment when I press a specific key of my keyboard. To do that I can define on a MX key a script to run what I want in using the steel series software (or I can directly select a softwre to run).

The anaconda environment I want to use is called "Python_36". any Idea on how to do that ?

In an anaconda prompt, I just have to run the "spyder" command and It run if I have loaded first the right environment with "conda activate Python_36" but how to write a script in a standard windows shell ?

Thanks for your help!

Lelorrain

In an anaconda prompt:

```
conda activate Python_36
spyder
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution. In fact, the conda prompt run a bat file in cmd shell, it is not a special program. As a result, here is what you have to do in a simple cmd window:

```
call <anaconda directory>\Scripts\activate.bat <anaconda directory>  && conda activate Python_36 && spyder
```

thanks to me :D